# Most efficient way to select elements in n dimension array in Ruby with indexes

Tags: arrays, ruby, multidimensional-array

I want to select elements with its indexes based on given condition for n dimension array

I have solution for two dimension array like below

```
ary = [
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['D', 'E', 'F'],
 ['G', 'H', 'I']
]

new_ary = ary.collect.with_index do |row, index_r|
  row.collect.with_index { |col, index_c| [col, index_r, index_c] if index_c == 0 }.compact
end  
new_ary.flatten(1)

=> [["A", 0, 0], ["D", 1, 0], ["G", 2, 0]]
```

I want this solution for n dimension

it would be great if method works like this

```
ary.select_with_indexes { |val, index_c ,index_c,...|  index_c == 0 }
# x,y,... is indexes
# val is value of x,y,... index 
# x == 0 is condition for select element, this condition is only for understanding.  we will put any condition there
```

Three dimension array like below

```
ary = [[
 ['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
 ['D1', 'E1', 'F1'],
 ['G1', 'H1', 'I1']
],[
 ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'],
 ['D2', 'E2', 'F2'],
 ['G2', 'H2', 'I2']
],[
 ['A3', 'B3', 'C3'],
 ['D3', 'E3', 'F3'],
 ['G3', 'H3', 'I3']
]]

new_ary = ary.collect.with_index do |row, index_r|
  row.collect.with_index do |col, index_c|
    col.collect.with_index do |val, index_d| 
      [val, index_r, index_c, index_d] if index_d == 0
    end.compact
  end  
end  

new_ary.flatten(1)

=> [[["A1", 0, 0, 0]], [["D1", 0, 1, 0]], [["G1", 0, 2, 0]], [["A2", 1, 0, 0]], [["D2", 1, 1, 0]], [["G2", 1, 2, 0]], [["A3", 2, 0, 0]], [["D3", 2, 1, 0]], [["G3", 2, 2, 0]]]
```

`index_d == 0` this condition is only for understanding
we will put any condition there

Comment: Please include an example for 3 dimensions.

Comment: I have included an example for 3 dimensions

Answer (score 0):

**Code**

In the examples in the question the index of the innermost array is always zero. I have made that an argument, `most_inner_index`.

```
def doit(ary, most_inner_index)
  first, *rest = nested_indices(ary)
  first.product(*rest).map do |indices|
    [ary.dig(*indices, most_inner_index), *indices, most_inner_index]
  end
end
```

```
def nested_indices(ary)
  sizes = []
  while ary.first.is_a?(Array)
    sizes << ary.size.times.to_a
    ary = ary.first
  end
  sizes
end
```

**Examples**

```
ary2 = [
 ['A', 'B', 'C'],
 ['D', 'E', 'F'],
 ['G', 'H', 'I']
]
```

```
doit(ary2, 0)
  #=> [["A", 0, 0], ["D", 1, 0], ["G", 2, 0]] 
doit(ary2, 1)
  #=> [["B", 0, 1], ["E", 1, 1], ["H", 2, 1]] 
doit(ary2, 2)
  #=> [["C", 0, 2], ["F", 1, 2], ["I", 2, 2]]
```

---

```
ary3 = [[
 ['A1', 'B1', 'C1'],
 ['D1', 'E1', 'F1'],
 ['G1', 'H1', 'I1']
],[
 ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'],
 ['D2', 'E2', 'F2'],
 ['G2', 'H2', 'I2']
],[
 ['A3', 'B3', 'C3'],
 ['D3', 'E3', 'F3'],
 ['G3', 'H3', 'I3']
]]
```

```
doit(ary3, 0)
  #=> [["A1", 0, 0, 0], ["D1", 0, 1, 0], ["G1", 0, 2, 0],
  #    ["A2", 1, 0, 0], ["D2", 1, 1, 0], ["G2", 1, 2, 0],
  #    ["A3", 2, 0, 0], ["D3", 2, 1, 0], ["G3", 2, 2, 0]] 
doit(ary3, 1)
  #=> [["B1", 0, 0, 1], ["E1", 0, 1, 1], ["H1", 0, 2, 1],
  #    ["B2", 1, 0, 1], ["E2", 1, 1, 1], ["H2", 1, 2, 1],
  #    ["B3", 2, 0, 1], ["E3", 2, 1, 1], ["H3", 2, 2, 1]] 
doit(ary3, 2)
  #=> [["C1", 0, 0, 2], ["F1", 0, 1, 2], ["I1", 0, 2, 2],
  #    ["C2", 1, 0, 2], ["F2", 1, 1, 2], ["I2", 1, 2, 2],
  #    ["C3", 2, 0, 2], ["F3", 2, 1, 2], ["I3", 2, 2, 2]]
```

Notice that the return values are not quite in the form desired. That is because I could not figure out from the question how many nested arrays were desired.

---

```
ary4 = [
         [
           [
             [['A1', 'B1'], ['C1', 'D1']],
             [['E1', 'F1'], ['G1', 'H1']]
           ],
           [  
             [['I1', 'J1'], ['K1', 'L1']],
             [['M1', 'N1'], ['O1', 'P1']]
           ]
         ],
         [ 
           [
             [['A2', 'B2'], ['C2', 'D2']],
             [['E2', 'F2'], ['G2', 'H2']]
           ],
           [ 
             [['I2', 'J2'], ['K2', 'L2']],
             [['M2', 'N2'], ['O2', 'P2']]
           ]
         ],
         [ 
           [
             [['A3', 'B3'], ['C3', 'D3']],
             [['E3', 'F3'], ['G3', 'H3']]
           ],
           [ 
             [['I3', 'J3'], ['K3', 'L3']],
             [['M3', 'N3'], ['O3', 'P3']]
           ]
         ]
       ]
```

```
doit(ary4, 0)
  #=> [["A1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["C1", 0, 0, 0, 1, 0], ["E1", 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
  #    ["G1", 0, 0, 1, 1, 0], ["I1", 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], ["K1", 0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
  #    ["M1", 0, 1, 1, 0, 0], ["O1", 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], ["A2", 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
  #    ["C2", 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], ["E2", 1, 0, 1, 0, 0], ["G2", 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
  #    ["I2", 1, 1, 0, 0, 0], ["K2", 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], ["M2", 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],
  #    ["O2", 1, 1, 1, 1, 0], ["A3", 2, 0, 0, 0, 0], ["C3", 2, 0, 0, 1, 0],
  #    ["E3", 2, 0, 1, 0, 0], ["G3", 2, 0, 1, 1, 0], ["I3", 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
  #    ["K3", 2, 1, 0, 1, 0], ["M3", 2, 1, 1, 0, 0], ["O3", 2, 1, 1, 1, 0]] 

doit(ary4, 1)
  #=> [["B1", 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], ["D1", 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], ["F1", 0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
  #    ["H1", 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], ["J1", 0, 1, 0, 0, 1], ["L1", 0, 1, 0, 1, 1],
  #    ["N1", 0, 1, 1, 0, 1], ["P1", 0, 1, 1, 1, 1], ["B2", 1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
  #    ["D2", 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], ["F2", 1, 0, 1, 0, 1], ["H2", 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
  #    ["J2", 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], ["L2", 1, 1, 0, 1, 1], ["N2", 1, 1, 1, 0, 1],
  #    ["P2", 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], ["B3", 2, 0, 0, 0, 1], ["D3", 2, 0, 0, 1, 1],
  #    ["F3", 2, 0, 1, 0, 1], ["H3", 2, 0, 1, 1, 1], ["J3", 2, 1, 0, 0, 1],
  #    ["L3", 2, 1, 0, 1, 1], ["N3", 2, 1, 1, 0, 1], ["P3", 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]]
```

**Explanation**

The steps are as follows for `ary3` and `most_inner_index = 0`.

```
a = nested_indices(ary3)
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
first, *rest = a
  #=> [[0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 2]]
```

Ruby applies [array decomposition](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.7.0/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) to obtain the following.

```
first
  #=> [0, 1, 2] 
rest
  #=> [[0, 1, 2]]
```

Continuing,

```
b = first.product(*rest) 
  #=> [[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [1, 0], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 0], [2, 1], [2, 2]] 

c = b.map do |indices|
  [ary.dig(*indices, most_inner_index), *indices, most_inner_index]
end
  #=> [["A1", 0, 0, 0], ["D1", 0, 1, 0], ["G1", 0, 2, 0],
  #    ["A2", 1, 0, 0], ["D2", 1, 1, 0], ["G2", 1, 2, 0],
  #    ["A3", 2, 0, 0], ["D3", 2, 1, 0], ["G3", 2, 2, 0]]
```

See [Array#product](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-product) and [Array#dig](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Array.html#method-i-dig).